# Ajax/jQuery e.preventDefault is preventing page refresh and form submit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

My I'm trying to use ajax/jQuery/php/html to **post my form without page reload**.

- When I add e.prevent default, the page does not refresh and the form does not post.
- When I take out e.prevent default, the form posts and the page refreshes.

What am I missing?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#send').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();        
      $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              $('#contactForm').fadeOut(600);
              $('#contactClick').hide().html('Thanks for the message! I&#39;ll get back to you shortly.').fadeIn(600);
              $('section#contact').height(windowHeight);
              $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:($('#contact').position().top)}, 'slow');
              }
      });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="index.php" method="post">

    <label class="col-xs-2">Name:</label>
    <input class="col-xs-12" id="name" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" />

    <label class="col-xs-2">Email:</label>
    <input class="col-xs-12" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" />

    <label class="col-xs-2">Message:</label>
    <textarea class="col-xs-12" id="message" rows="10" cols="10" autocomplete="off" name="message"></textarea>

    <input id="send" class="submit" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

Here is my PHP (this is at the top of my index.php file):

```
<?php 
if($_POST['formSubmit']=="Send") {

$to = "myemail@ddress.com";
$subject = "A message from your website";

$text = " Name: ";
$text .= $_POST['name'];
$text .= "\r\n";
$text .= " E-mail: ";
$text .= $_POST['email'];
$text .= "\r\n";
$text .= " Message: ";
$text .= $_POST['message'];
$text .= "\r\n";
$wrapped_text = wordwrap($text, 120, "\r\n");
$message = htmlentities($wrapped_text);

mail($to,$subject,$message);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you make it a button instead of a submit in your form?

```
<input id="send" class="submit" type="button" name="formSubmit" value="Send" />
```

And removing the action and methods attributes from your form... so that it looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
```

Remove the preventDefault() and in your data parameter do this:

```
data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
```

Edit: Oh, and put the php script that sends the mail into another file (e.g. sendMail.php).

Hope that works :)

Answer (score 0):

I would print the 3 variables used to send the email before the send line, and in the javascript put alert (data) in the ajax success function and see if all is correct.